# Send a string from C# to C++

Tags: c#, c++, visual-c++

I have a C++ program which does some processing on a `char search[500]` array. The dodge here is that the `search[]` has to be assigned value from C# program.

Consider, that I have this C# program which gets user's input from `textbox` and have to send this `string` to C#.

I have been able to export the data, functions and variables from C++ to C#, but I am not familiar how the reverse is done.

```
[DllImport("Test.dll", EntryPoint = "fnmain", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl , CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
private static extern int fnmain();//pass what in parameter?
```

C++

```
//search[] parameter has to be here. What type to be assigned to get from C# and further get search[] char array
    int main(char search[])
    {
    ..
    }
```

Comment: Show your actual C++ function signature, not just your C# approximation.

Comment: Should the C++ function be named "fnmain" instead of "main"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want search to be a `string`. I believe CharSet.Ansi is all you need to make sure the interop converts strings to char *.

Comment: Does that mean on calling function in C# `fnmain(string searchtext)` will automatically convert it to `fnmain(char search[])` for C++ interop?

Comment: And no marshalling etc. required here?

Comment: @Ramhound : Or he could try it and get silent memory corruption or a memory leak and not know it. He came to SO to get an accurate answer -- "try it yourself" is not useful.

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant. There will be marshaling, but it will be done for you.

Answer (score 0):

This may sound silly. Have you considered calling C++ program with command line arguments? If initialization takes a lot of time, you can use concepts of pipes or read/write from or to files. If you can do a little bit of socket programming, that would mean true asynchronous passing of data. Hope this helped.